# Insert Face and save it as a plane

Tags: faces

I'm wondering if it's possible to save an inserted face (f key) as new mesh?

Thank you

Comment: You can separate any selected mesh and create a new object by typing "P" or going into Mesh>Separate then choose "Selection". Is this what you were trying to do ?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much